# Selenium webdriver-clear method usage while selecting a value from drop down element

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

In `selenium webdriver`, I am using hybrid framework. In that at run time while selecting value from `dropdown list` its not selecting the correct value, instead selecting already selected value.

Should I use `clear()` method for drop down?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: please edit your response to also post your code

Answer (score 1):

Is it traditional **select** combo Box or a widget combo box, paste relevant HTMl code please. Also if its traditional combo box then try printing all the options and see if you are able to see all the values..Clear method will just clear the current value selected (defaulted)